# Handle no reusable component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm struggling with following the React philosophy of reusing components.

I have three screens (Screen1, Screen2) that are used as tabs in different pages along my application (Page1, Page2), but these screens are not the same for each page, they differ slightly in the text of labels, buttons, etc that they have. And there is a component, a panel, that is shared among all the screens of a certain page.

Should I create each screen as a different component for each page? Resulting in 4 screen components (two for Page1 and two for Page2)? If yes, should I define them in a different folder than the regular components folder? Because they wouldn't be reusable. Or should I create a reusable component and pass to it the data it should display as json for e.g.?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The question of "Should I extract this as a Component?" is too situational to answer. So it depends on:

- How many times will you copy-paste very similar code?
- Will they change separately in future? Are their requirements different?
- Does the extracted reusable component become extremely long/complex when you combine them?

These are the questions you need to answer.